# tsql stored procedure convert to vb.net : will temp tables hold up?

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code in a stored procedure:

```
select
    i.ItemID
    ,cast(p.PropertyValue as varchar(100)) as Custodian
    ,cast(null as int) as PersonID
    ,cast(null as bit) as Child
into #c 
from tblItem as I
inner join tblExternalData_Matches as m on I.ItemID = m.ItemID
inner join tblItemExtendedProperties as p on I.ItemID = p.ItemID and p.[Application] = 'Import' and p.PropertyName = 'File Owner'
where m.SourceID = @SourceID

--Update PersonID for custodians we already have
update c set
c.PersonID = p.PersonID
from #c as c
inner join tblPerson as p on c.custodian = p.NameDisplay
```

what would be the most memory efficient way in converting this? 
should i just select the results into datatable types?

Answer (score 0):

A DataTable is not the most memory efficient type to use but it all depends on what you will be doing with the data.

Take a look at the DataReader for the most efficient way to work through a record set.

Here's a great [blog entry](http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2005/04/25/37618.aspx) that compares DataSets and DataReaders and will help you decide which way to go.

Comment: is a datareader readonly and forward only?  I need a way to update the items inside the recordset object without affecting the database from which it came from, such as a temporary table for the session.

Comment: In that case you should be using the DataSets/DataTables